# Loop through array and delete duplicates PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$rows` that looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [object_id] => 1
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => category
            [object_id] => 46
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => product
            [object_id] => 50
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => category
            [object_id] => 59
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [object_id] => 1
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )
)
```

I need to loop through this array and when a duplicate `type` and `object_id` matches, increment the score and delete the duplicate array. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Using the example above, key 0 has `type` `post` and `object_id` `1`, and so does key 4. Key 0 `score` should be incremented to itself + key 4 `score` and key 4 should be deleted.

My end result should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => post
            [object_id] => 1
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => category
            [object_id] => 46
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => product
            [object_id] => 50
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => category
            [object_id] => 59
            [language_id] => 1
            [score] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: Post your attempts along with expected output

Comment: Just rewrite a new function to merge your array with itself.

Comment: Try array_values(array_unique($array))

Comment: How is this going to increment the score of the existing type/object_id array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that simply using `foreach` as

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $hash = $value['type'];
    $hash1 = $value['object_id'];
    if (isset($result[$hash.$hash1]['type']) && isset($result[$hash.$hash1]['object_id'])) {
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['type'] = $value['type'];
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['object_id'] = $value['object_id'];
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['language_id'] = $value['language_id'];
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['score'] += $value['score'];
    } else {
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['type'] = $value['type'];
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['object_id'] = $value['object_id'];
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['language_id'] = $value['language_id'];
        $result[$hash.$hash1]['score'] = $value['score'];
    }
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/416162)

Comment: Perfect, I had to do an additional `array_multisort` and adjust my initial count for the new items in the array, but overall, perfect.  Thanks so much!